# C++ code performance parallel implementation

Tags: python, c++

Suppose I compile code that uses parallelization, on a machine with 2 cores and create a shared library file(.so) and use that shared library to call the CPP function in python on 2 cores machine to get a benchmark time t1. Now I take all the same files to a machine with 16 cores to get benchmark time t2.
To get t2 <<<< t1

1. Do I need to recompile the code and create a shared library on the new machine?
2. Parallelization is not possible since I am using python to call the function?

Currently, I am getting t1 ~ t2.
Compiler - GCC

If it helps the parallel code is from [pargeo](https://github.com/wangyiqiu/pargeo.git) library to compute EMST. I have compiled the code using exact instructions provided in the repository with one change in CMake file(Enabling pybinding on Line 10)

Comment: I don't know pargeo, but note that how well code parallelizes usually depends a lot on the code being parallelized. For example, you could have all the cores in use and get bound up on a shared resource like IO.

Comment: Regarding 1: I don't know. This is specific to the library. Regarding 2: If there is only one call at a time from Python into the library and not from multiple Python threads at the same time and the parallelization is done entirely in the C++ library, it doesn't matter that the call is coming from Python and parallelization should work.

Comment: A bit of context, python just provides a 2d array to CPP function and CPP function just returns a 2d array. There are no multiple processes in python. In on single run, the CPP function will get called only once. So, I guess the second is out of the question.

Comment: Assuming the worst case, that parallelization code is not written properly(That should not be the case), I should be able to some improvement over code running in 2 core machine right? And it should never happen that t2 > t1?

Comment: Also remember to build with compiler optimizations enabled.

Comment: *And it should never happen that t2 > t1?* sadly, no. An example: In deviant cases information sharing between the threads can get more expensive as you add threads, eating up and ultimately exceeding the savings from the extra threads.

Comment: How do you do that using cmake?@JesperJuhl